# IdentationError? what's wrong here?

Tags: python

> if choice1 == "left":
> choice2 = input('You've come to a lake. There is an island in the middle of the lake. Type "wait" to wait foraboat. Type "swim" to swim across.\n').lower()
> if choice2 == "wait":
> choice3 == input("You arrived at the island unharmed. There is a house with 3 doors. One red, one yellow, and one blue. Which colour do you choose?\n").lower()
> if choice3 == "red":
> print("Game Over.")
> elif choice3 == "yellow":
> print("You found the treasure! You Win!")
> elif choice3 == "blue":
> print("You enter a room full of beasts. Game Over!")

'if choice1 == "left":
choice2 = input('You've come to a lake. There is an island in the middle of the lake. Type "wait" to wait foraboat. Type "swim" to swim across.\n').lower()
if choice2 == "wait":
choice3 == input("You arrived at the island unharmed. There is a house with 3 doors. One red, one yellow, and one blue. Which colour do you choose?\n").lower()'
if choice3 == "red":
print("Game Over.")
elif choice3 == "yellow":
print("You found the treasure! You Win!")
elif choice3 == "blue":
print("You enter a room full of beasts. Game Over!")

Comment: you have an extra space

Comment: Line 33 has an illegal indentation (add a space in front)

Comment: Unindent line 34. And use 4 spaces for indentation - it's much clearer, and it's the [official recommendation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Post as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`choice2 = input(...` has a different number of spaces in front of it than the rest of the body of the `if choice1 == "left"` statement.

Comment: File "main.py", line 36
    if choice3 == "red":
                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level 

and what is that?